# dynamic page link id_user fixed on index

Tags: php, mysql

I have created a dynamic page using PHP similar to the example here http://tutorialweb.net/membuat-halaman-dinamis-dengan-php/ . It is running successfully, I have one page `list.php` which contains a link like this:

```
<a href="edit.php?uid=<?php echo $data ['id_user']; ?>">View</a>
```

and redirect to `edit.php` page

How can I load the contents of `edit.php` while remaining in `index.php` (without redirection).

Comment: thanks for edit my question Amal Murali

Answer (score -1):

in index.php, do an inlusion like this:

```
include('./edit.php');
```

or use include_once, require or require_once

Comment: please see my page edit.php code in the following pastebin link here http://pastebin.com/yzxuMRVi